# Access variable from another JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two JS files, `base_player.js` and `station.js`.

I have some logic in base_player.js that needs access to a value that comes from station.js. While the var is 'global', it is wrapped in a namepace `mm.Station`. The value I need is a UUID of a selected station:

```
mm.Station = function($el) {
  "use strict";

  if (_.isUndefined($el)) {
    return;
  }

  var self = mm.EventEmitter();
  var $actions;
  self.uuid = $el.attr("data-uuid");

  .........
```

I feed any selected station with songs in batches at a certain point in a queue. This logic all happens in `base_player.js`.

I want to get the UUID from station.js to use in this GET in base_player.js:

```
mm.BasePlayer = function ($el) {
........

  function feedSelectedStation(uuid) {
    if(_.isUndefined(uuid)){
      return false;
      }

    $.get('/feed-station/' + uuid)
      .done(function (data) {
        console.log('feedSelectedStation');
        if(!_.has(data, "list")){ return; }
        self.queue = self.queue.concat(data.list);
    });
  }
.........
```

I don't write much Javascript so I'm a bit unsure how to achieve this. Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: Use cookies or localStorage (and google).

Comment: If both scripts are included and executed with `<script>` tags in the header, shouldn't variables be accessible from both scripts to each other? Have you tried simply accessing the global variable from the other script?

Comment: Looks like `uuid` is part of some element attribute in the DOM. I suggest you pick it up from there, unless `uuid` changes in your first script.

Comment: Is `mm.Station` defined when `mm.BasePlayer` is loaded ?

Comment: The other function needs to access `mm.eventEmitter().uuid`.